# Theme + dynamic control creation + Invisible UserControl = view state error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

default2.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Theme="Blue" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="favicon" Src="~/FavIcon.ascx" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<script runat="server">


    private void Page_PreRender(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl scriptControl = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
        Page.Header.Controls.AddAt(0, scriptControl);//If this line is commented out, no exception will occur.
    }


    private void Page_Init(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager oSM = new ScriptManager();
        Page.Form.Controls.Add(oSM);//If this line is commented out, no exception will occur.
    }


</script>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <uc1:favicon runat="server"></uc1:favicon>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

FavIcon.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" ClassName="FavIcon" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<script runat="server">

    void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Visible = false;//If this line is commented out, no exception will occur.
    }

</script>
```

Also add a stylesheet to the Blue theme.

[image: Also add a stylesheet to the Blue theme.]

The page opens successfully, but once I click the button, it throws exception

> Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is
>   being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save
>   viewstate during the previous request.  For example, when adding
>   controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match
>   the type and position of the controls added during the initial
>   request.

Can anyone explain why this error happens?

Comment: This is the classic error you get when you combine viewstate (enabled by default) with dynamic controls (controls.Addxxx) : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2011/10/25/why-we-get-the-exception-failed-to-load-viewstate/  (theme=blue adds a control dynamically, Visible=true adds information to the viewstate, etc.).

Comment: @SimonMourier The error only happens when the three factors exist. Can you explain why the error doesn't happen when I remove any one of the three factors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug these errors, I strongly recommend to enable traces (Trace="true" in the @page directive, or use a [global setting in web.config](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420.aspx)) so you can see the server's control tree.

On a GET, the control tree is this (note the unique IDs that were generated automatically):

```
  HtmlHead
    + ctl05 : HtmlGenericControl (from your PreRender code)
    + ctl01 : Title (the <title> tag)
    + ctl02 : FavIcon (your favicon.ascx)
    + ctl04 : HtmlLink (from the 'Blue' theme)

  HtmlForm
    + ctl03 : ScriptManager
```

The root causes of the 'Failed To Load ViewState' error are:

- *you use the ViewState*. This is an option that in many cases can be disabled.
- *you don't use fixed IDs* (that's why the Visual Studio's IDE adds automatic but fixed IDs to controls all the time).
- *you add controls dynamically, late, in the tree*, as it changes the head's control tree. Plus, you add it before others (AddAt).

The generated IDs follow ASP.NET's [lifecycle order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx):

1. Title (static)
2. FavIcon (static)
3. ScriptManager (Init)
4. Theme (Init, after overrides)
5. Dynamic controls (After Init in this case)

The ASP.NET ViewState engine is a tree serializer/deserializer. Each node in the tree has it's IDs, plus a "full ID" composed of its parent's IDs and its own ID. Of course, as soon as you change IDs between serialization and deserialization, all bets are off, the engine will detect it and raise the 'Failed to Load ViewState' error.

So, if you put `Visible=false`, you'll use the ViewState. If you remove it, you won't. When you don't use the ViewState yourself, there are less chances to get the 'Failed to load viewstate' error, but ASP.NET can use some ViewState on your behalf when you use all its features (Theme, etc.). In the case of Visible, it just means the control is there (and uses ViewState), but not rendered (it's Render Size is 0). But you'll see the problem with any other property that use the ViewState, it's not specific to the Visible property (you could also try `this.ViewState["test"] = "whatever"` ).

If you put `<uc1:favicon runat="server"></uc1:favicon>` elsewhere in the page, it will also work because it won't be in the Head control tree anymore, and won't interfere with Theme's link or your dynamic control.

For Theme and ScriptManager, it's just that when you play with them, it changes, or not, the IDs, and the system may detect it or not.

There is an infinite number of ways to break the ViewState. What's really difficult is it may seem to work when it shouldn't (for example as long as you don't use FavIcon's ViewState, you don't notice there is an issue with your code).

Answer (score 1):

It happens due to the nature of ViewState. Briefly, when your page is being posted back a control into which ViewState is restored is matched by the control index, so when the index changes it causes this problem.
In this case, setting the property this way `ViewStateMode="Disabled"` for your page or changing the order you add your dynamic elements `Page.Header.Controls.AddAt(Page.Header.Controls.Count, scriptControl)`, which lets you not interfere with the order of restored elements, can help you cope with the trouble. At least, it works out for me.

Comment: Can you explain what the control tree differences are between inital load and postback? Why doesn't the error happen if I don't add ScriptManager dynamically while leaving other code alone?

Comment: 1. Initially, your ViewState is empty and the process of saving to ViewState takes place after rendering, when you have already added all your dynamic controls. During the postback loading controls from ViewState happens before rendering itself, it means, that the dynamic controls haven't been added yet. That's what breaks the order. Here is more about the order of the lifecycle of a page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

Comment: 2. On the other hand, you don't get this mistake all the time, because when loading from ViewState, only the order of elements is important, but not their types. Which means, that sometimes, despite another order, you might not run into this problem, as an expected element was substituted with a similar one. But when elements are completely different it causes this mistake. Here is more about this process with some relevant examples: http://geekswithblogs.net/FrostRed/archive/2007/02/17/106547.aspx

Comment: I only encounter this trouble when having Theme, scriptControl, added at the beginning of controls, and the FavIcon element (Visible=false) simultaneously. The index of FavIcon element is 2 (the third control after adding scriptControl) when it's saved to ViewState. After the postback it tries to retrieve it from ViewState, but there is Theme (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink) on that position (scriptControl hasn't added yet). Apparently, these two kinds of controls are incompatible (the problem of expecting pairs instead of triples when loading a state), which causes the mistake.

Comment: I don't have that mistake with ScriptManager, as you depicted (perhaps, various versions of some frameworks), but I'm sure, that this logic is equal in any case. It might be easier to understand, if you try overriding the LoadViewState method for your control as well as overriding a method SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium for your page and look into the sequence of loading the page and its controls.

Comment: Since I add scriptControl in `PreRender` stage, in postback `LoadViewState` event, view state mismatches the current control tree.  So if the header has any other controls using view state, the error is likely to happen. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: If I add `scriptControl.EnableViewState = false;`, the element should not use view state any more, why do I still get the error?

Comment: You and @Simon are equally helpful! Since your most helpful parts are the comments and they were posted later than Simon, I have to accept his. Hope you understand.

Comment: Yes, the mistake is likely to happen in that case, but as you can see there might be some exceptions out of this rule. The problem happens to the `FavIcon` control, not with `scriptControl`. ViewState is trying to restore `FavIcon`, but `scriptControl` only interferes with the order. Try `<uc1:favicon runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled"></uc1:favicon>` instead and you'll see the difference.